# Using Queryable Extension to get back Foreign Key Data Value

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have my Unit of Measure which users fill in and save, they can then save a list of Unit Sizes which has its own table and is a foreign key to the Unit Of Measure. When I am fetching all the data back, the Unit Size value is coming back blank.

I have read a half dozen ways to do this and I am not comprehending them. The one that makes the most sense to me is using a Queryable extension so I am trying to go that route but my code still hasn't quite gotten there.

Here is where I am at - these are my entities:

```
namespace Mudman.Data.Entities
{   
    [Table("UnitOfMeasure")]
    public class UnitOfMeasure : IEntityBase, IAuditBase
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("UnitOfMeasureId")]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("TenantId")]
        public string TenantId { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual Tenant Tenant { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual IEnumerable<UnitOfMeasureSize> UnitSize { get; set; }

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;

        [StringLength(255)]
        public string CreateUserId { get; set; }

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }

        [StringLength(255)]
        public string UpdateUserId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Unit Of Measure size entity:

```
namespace Mudman.Data.Entities
{
    [Table("UnitOfMeasureSize")]
    public class UnitOfMeasureSize : IEntityBase, IAuditBase
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("UnitOfMeasureSize")]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("TenantId")]
        public string TenantId { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual Tenant Tenant { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("UnitOfMeasureId")]
        public string UnitOfMeasureId { get; set; }
        public virtual UnitOfMeasure UnitOfMeasure { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int UnitSize { get; set; }

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;

        [StringLength(255)]
        public string CreateUserId { get; set; }

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }

        [StringLength(255)]
        public string UpdateUserId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Unit Of Measure Repository including Unit Size:

```
namespace Mudman.Repository
{
   public class UnitOfMeasureRepository : EntityBaseRepository<UnitOfMeasure>, 
   IUnitOfMeasureRepository
   {
       MudmanDbContext context;

       public UnitOfMeasureRepository(MudmanDbContext context) : base(context)
       {
            { this.context = context; };
       }

       public  IEnumerable<UnitOfMeasure> GetAllUnitsOfMeasure(string TenantId)
       {
            var result =  context.UnitOfMeasure
                                 .Where( uom => uom.TenantId == TenantId)
                                 .Include(uom => uom.UnitSize);

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

My `GetAllAsync` method in my service:

```
 public  Task<IEnumerable<UnitOfMeasureViewModel>> GetAllAsync()
 {    
     var result =  _unitOfMeasureRepo.GetAllUnitsOfMeasure(TenantId);
     result.OrderBy(r => r.Name);
     
     return _mapper.Map<List<UnitOfMeasure>, List<UnitOfMeasureViewModel>>(result.ToList());
 }
```

AutoMapper Code:

```
    CreateMap<UnitOfMeasure, UnitOfMeasureViewModel>().ReverseMap()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.UnitSize, uos => uos.Ignore())
        .ForMember(uom => uom.UnitSize, src => src.MapFrom(uom => uom.UnitSize));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your attempts so far.

Firstly, your GetAllAsync looks like it wants to be an `async` method but you have it making entirely synchronous calls, and hasn't been marked as `async`. I would avoid diving into asynchronous methods until you have the fundamentals of retrieving your data down.

What we cannot see from your example is the mapping between your unit of measure entity and the view model. The entity has a one-to-many relationship between unit of measure and UnitSizes, so what gets updated depends on how the view model is laid out and configured for mapping. This is most likely the root of your problem where your view model mapping from the entity is likely relying on a convention that isn't pairing up with the data you expect.

Performance wise, this approach will run into problems as your data model grows in terms of entities and rows. The fundamental problem with using a repository like this is that a method like this:

```
IEnumerable<UnitOfMeasure> GetAllUnitsOfMeasure(string TenantId)
```

will load all data into memory and you explicitly need to include related entities, whether the consumer will want them or not, which adds to the amount of work the queries need to do and the memory required.  If TenantId is for something like a multi-tenant database such as in a SaaS application with multiple tenants using a single data source, this is a good reason to adopt a Repository pattern, but I would not pass tenantIds around as parameters. Instead, have the repository accept a dependency that can validate and resolve the current TenantId from the session. This way the repository can always ensure that the current tenant rules are validated and applied for every query without worrying about where the caller might have gotten a TenantId from. (I.e accepting a TenantId from a POST request would be bad as that value could easily be tampered with)

To address performance and probably touch on what you had read about `IQueryable` extensions, rather than returning `IEnumerable<TEntity>` from a repository, you can return `IQueryable<TEntity>`. The advantages here are that you can still have the repository add base filtering rules like the tenantID, and allow the consumer to handle things like sorting and projection.

For example, the repository looks more like:

```
public class UnitOfMeasureRepository : IUnitOfMeasureRepository
{
    private readonly MudmanDbContext _context;
    private readonly ICurrentUserLocator _currentUserLocator;

    public UnitOfMeasureRepository(MudmanDbContext context, ICurrentUserLocator currentUserLocator ) 
    {
         _context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
         _currentUserLocator = currentUserLocator ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("currentUserLocator");
    } 

    public  IQueryable<UnitOfMeasure> GetUnitsOfMeasure()
    {
         var tenantId = _currentUserLocator.CurrentUserTenantId; // Checks session for current user and retrieves a tenant ID or throws an exception. (no session, etc.)
         var query = _context.UnitOfMeasure
             .Where( uom => uom.TenantId == tenantId)

         return query;
     }
}
```

The changes to note here is that we do away with the base generic repository class. This was confusing as you were passing the context to a base class then setting a local context instance as well. Generic repositories with EF are a bad code smell as they lead to either very complex code, very poor performing code, or both. There is a CurrentUserLocator with the container can inject which is a simple class that can verify that a user is currently authenticated and can return their Tenant ID. From there we will return an `IQueryable<UnitOfMeasure>` which has a base filter for the TenantID which will allow our consumers to make up their own minds how they want to consume it. Note that we do not need to use `Include` for related entities, again the consumers can decide what they need.

Calling the new repository method and projecting your view models looks fairly similar to what you had. It looks like you are using Automapper, rather than using `.Map()` we can use `.ProjectTo()` with the `IQueryable` and Automapper can essentially build a `Select()` expression to pull back only the data that the view model will need. To use `ProjectTo` extension method we do need to provide it with the MappingConfiguration that was used to create your mapper and that will tell it how to build the ViewModel. (So rather than having a dependency of type 'Mapper' you will need one for the `MapperConfiguration` you set up for that mapper.)

```
public  IEnumerable<UnitOfMeasureViewModel> GetAll()
{    
     var models =  _unitOfMeasureRepo.GetUnitsOfMeasure()
         .OrderBy(r => r.Name)
         .ProjectTo<UnitOfMeasureViewModel>(_mapperConfiguration)
         .ToList();
}
```

What this does is call our repository method to get the `IQueryable`, which we can then append the ordering we desire, and call `ProjectTo` to allow Automapper to populate the view models before executing the query with `ToList()`. When using `Select` or `ProjectTo` we don't need to worry about using `Include` to eager load related data that might be mapped, these methods take care of loading data related entities if/when needed automatically.

Even in cases where we want to use a method like this to update entities with related entities, using `IQueryable` works there to:

```
public void IncrementUnitSize(string unitOfMeasureId)
{    
     var unitOfMeasure =  _unitOfMeasureRepo.GetUnitsOfMeasure()
         .Include(r => r.UnitSizes)
         .Where(r => r.Id == unitOfMeasureId)
         .Single();

     foreach(var unitSize in unitOfMeasure.UnitSizes)
         unitSize.UnitSize += 1;

     _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Just as an example of fetching related entities as needed, versus having a method that returns `IEnumerable` and needs to eager load everything just in case some caller might need it.

These methods can very easily be translated into an asyncronous method without touching the repository:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<UnitOfMeasureViewModel>> GetAll()
{    
     var models =  await _unitOfMeasureRepo.GetAllUnitsOfMeasure(TenantId)
         .OrderBy(r => r.Name)
         .ProjectTo<UnitOfMeasureViewModel>(_mapperConfiguration)
         .ToListAsync();
}
```

... and that is all! Just remember that `async` doesn't make the call faster, if anything it makes it a touch slower. What it does is make the server more responsive by allowing it to move the request handling to a background thread and free the request thread to pick up a new server request. That is great for methods that are going to take a bit of time, or are going to get called very frequently to avoid tying down all of the server request threads leading to timeouts for users waiting for a response from the server. For methods that are very fast and aren't expected to get hammered by a lot of users, `async` doesn't add a lot of value and you need to ensure every async call is awaited or you can end up with whacky behaviour and exceptions.